# jQuery Sortable drag and drop does not work as expected

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I have an ordered list of textareas and I'm using jQuery Sortable to enable drag and drop to reposition items on the list. The drag and drop appears to work, but when I try to save the list, it's saved in the original order, not the displayed order. Is this how Sortable is supposed to work?

Answer (score 0):

Are you ordering textareas on a page, and then expecting them to go to the server in the order they were put in?  If so, you can not rely on such things.  Browsers are not required to send fields in the order they are placed on a page, and you never know what the server might do with the request data on the way in.

Whenever I deal with sorting things in jQuery, I use JavaScript to read the order of the items for me, and then pass the order in a hidden field... So if all of your text areas have id's, you could have a hidden field named "sort_order" with the values being a comma-delimited list of ids, in the right order.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I did a similar thing using the jQuery each() function and renaming the items according to the order my server code expects and that works like a charm. Thanks again.